# Aligning text with a big letter first

Tags: css

I have a grouping a text that the user wants the First letter of each line to spell a word vertically.

**R**ESPONSIVE

**E**FFICIENT

**G**REATER GOOD

**I**NNOVATION

**O**PEN

**N**EIGHBORLY

See [thie fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeWills/8omta6ks/) for a better exmple of what I am trying to do. We are thinking it would present better if the rest of the content aligns with each other, but avoiding a table to display the information. More like:

```
R  ESPONSIVE
E  FFICIENT
G  REATER GOOD
I  NNOVATION
O  PEN
N  EIGHBORLY
```

I tried a margin, but that didn't help. I want to align the "ESPONSIVE", "FFICIENT", "REATER GOOD", "NNOVATION", "PEN", and "EIGHBORLY".

I am weak in my CSS-fu and can someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the layout you require the first letters would, ideally, need to be the same width (a monospace font).

Then you can just declare them as inline-block and add padding.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono);
 h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
h1:first-letter {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<h1>RESPONSIVE - Prompt to respond and serve</h1>
<h1>EFFICIENT - Highest performance at greatest economy</h1>
<h1>GREATER GOOD - Serve for the good of the community and region</h1>
<h1>INNOVATION - Embracing new ideas and methods to improve service delivery</h1>
<h1>OPEN - Spirit of accessibility in policy making and operation</h1>
<h1>NEIGHBORLY - Concern and compassion for others</h1>
```

As an alternative, amend the structure and it gets even simpler and no special fonts are required.

```css
h1 {
    font-size:1rem;
}

h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
    font-size:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>R</span>ESPONSIVE - Prompt to respond and serve</h1>
<h1><span>E</span>FFICIENT - Highest performance at greatest economy</h1>
<h1><span>G</span>REATER GOOD - Serve for the good of the community and region</h1>
<h1><span>I</span>NNOVATION - Embracing new ideas and methods to improve service delivery</h1>
<h1><span>O</span>PEN - Spirit of accessibility in policy making and operation</h1>
<h1><span>N</span>EIGHBORLY - Concern and compassion for others</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add css

```css
 h1:first-letter{
        display: inline-block;
padding-right: 10px;

    }
```

```html
<h1>R<span style="font-size:x-small;">ESPONSIVE - Prompt to respond and serve</span></h1>
<h1>E<span style="font-size:x-small;">FFICIENT - Highest performance at greatest economy</span></h1>
<h1>G<span style="font-size:x-small;">REATER GOOD - Serve for the good of the community and region</span></h1>
<h1>I<span style="font-size:x-small;">NNOVATION - Embracing new ideas and methods to improve service delivery</span></h1>
<h1>O<span style="font-size:x-small;">PEN - Spirit of accessibility in policy making and operation</span></h1>
<h1>N<span style="font-size:x-small;">EIGHBORLY - Concern and compassion for others</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case padding is better than margin. Margin is only for blocks or inline-blocks. Span is an inline element.

Your modified example will look like this:

```
<h1>R<span style="font-size:x-small; padding-left: 10px;">ESPONSIVE - Prompt to respond and serve</span></h1>
```

And you might want to apply one class to all spans: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeWills/8omta6ks/.

```css
.smaller {
   font-size:x-small; 
   padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<h1>R<span class="smaller">ESPONSIVE - Prompt to respond and serve</span></h1>
<h1>E<span class="smaller">FFICIENT - Highest performance at greatest economy</span></h1>
<h1>G<span class="smaller">REATER GOOD - Serve for the good of the community and region</span></h1>
<h1>I<span  class="smaller">NNOVATION - Embracing new ideas and methods to improve service delivery</span></h1>
<h1>O<span  class="smaller">PEN - Spirit of accessibility in policy making and operation</span></h1>
<h1>N<span  class="smaller">EIGHBORLY - Concern and compassion for others</span></h1>
```